# Rust - как проверить существование файла

Tags: windows, rust

Как узнать существует ли файл или нет по директории (`PathBuf`) через `rust` используя `match`.

Comment: Ну раз вы уже знаете PathBuf, то открыть документацию и увидеть метод [exists](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.exists) могли бы и сами, наверное... И непонятно зачем тут match

Comment: Я пробовал, но не работает

Comment: Что пробовали и почему не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему не решил, но использовал `Path`, вместо `PathBuf`.

Comment: PathBuf.exists и Path.exists это буквально один и тот же метод, так что непонятно что у вас за дичь там происходит